# Direct Mapping Cache Exercise

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, memory-address, cpu-cache

Consider a computer with the following characteristics: total of 1Gbyte of main
memory; word size of 1 byte; block size of 32 bytes; and cache size of 128 Kbytes.

a)For the main memory addresses of 11101234 and 0FFCABBE, give the
corresponding tag, cache line address, and word values for a direct-mapped
cache.

b) Give any two main memory addresses (based on the format identified in (a) with
different tags that map to the same cache line for a direct-mapped cache.

Please help me to solve it. I tried to do it but i am not sure if it is correct. also, it's bit confusing for me because the main memory size is 1GB but the address (11101234) when converted is bigger. Explanations as to why would be extremely helpful as i'm trying to understand how to work these out for further understanding.

Comment: `0x11101234` is smaller than 2^30; it's in the low 1GiB of physical address space.  The highest address is `0x3fffffff` (2^30 - 1), for a 1GB byte-addressable address-space.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I still don't understand. I mean 11101234 when converted to binary is 0001 0001 0001 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 . It has 32 digits. So, when we assigned the numbers to tag, line and offset, there are two extra numbers.

Comment: You chose to use three leading zeros when writing it down in base 2.  If you don't do that, it fits in 30 bits.

Comment: Ohh .. so that means we can exclude the three leading zeros?

Comment: Addresses are unsigned numbers.  With unsigned numbers you can add or remove leading zeros without changing the value.

Comment: Just one more question, so when  11101234 is converted it will become 01 0001 0001 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 right? . So when assigned to tag, line and offset. The tag = 0100010001000, line = 000010010001 and  word = 10100. Am i doing it correctly?

Comment: That looks right.  log2(32)=5, so 5 bits for the offset; there are 4096 block b/c 128kB/32B=4096, and log2(4096)=12 so that's 12 bits for the index, and the rest is the tag.

Comment: If I had authored this homework question, I would have said max capacity of 1GB, or address bus that is 30 bits wide; saying that "a computer has a total of 1GB of main memory" is imprecise, since many computers have less (total installed) ram than their max supported amount, though in this context the only reasonable way to interpret that information is as a max, since that's what you need to complete the cache analysis.